# Use Different database for different tables in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I am using WordPress Platform for my website.And its growing constantly.
We often ,do lots of experiments and customization on it.
Now we like to use a developer website to do all these experiments.Thing is i like to use the same settings and everything for my developer site,so everything should match the live website.

My problem is,i can setup the whole new mirror site ,but since we will have different database for our test site,the posts won't be updated to it,when its published on live site.
So is there a way,i can use my post table of live site on developer site.
i.e everything will be of its own on developer site,but it will fetch posts from live site.

Comment: Cerate a cronjob that will export changes on your live database import(updateing existing tables on test environment) to test databas

Comment: well,that would be the worst scenario , we are more concern about making it as much live as possible.Is it possible,if we can use two different database on one wordpress site.

Comment: the developer database you have could be a slave database which gets data everytime your master database is updated. see this for more info. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql. However, I would highly discourage this for development databases and go for the cron approach as @themarchoftheblackqueen has suggested

Comment: The cron job is the best solution, but you'll also need to run a find and replace if the urls are different on the dev and production environments.  WP Migrate DB Pro offers an out of the box solution as well if you're willing to part with some cash.